# Where's the error in this program that prints a matrix?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I created a matrix program that takes in the words from a file and prints them out either horizontally or vertically. The program checks if the character of a word is already in a spot or if the spot is blank in order to make sure it prints out properly. If a word or character is printed on top of another word or character then a new spot is generated to put the word in. This is done until the word can be printed without error. The blank spaces are filled with the letter 'A'.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordSearch {

public WordSearch() {

}

public void getMatrix() throws FileNotFoundException {



    File file = new File("/home/cameron/Desktop/words");

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    String largest = "";

    char[][] data;

    int col = 0;




    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);


    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {


        String first = sc.nextLine();

        words.add(first);


        if(first.length()>largest.length()){



         largest=first;

         col=largest.length();

        }
    }



        data = new char[col][col];

        int curWord=0;


        for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++){
            String word=words.get(curWord);  
            int start=0;
            int row=0;
            int choice=0;
            int index=0;


         do
         {

           start = (int)(Math.random()*data.length);
           row =  (int)(Math.random()*data.length);
           choice = (int)(Math.random()*2);

         }
         while(start+word.length()>data.length);



         index=0;

         if(choice==0){
             for(int j=start; j<start+word.length(); j++){              
                 if(data[row][j]==0 || data[row][j]==word.charAt(index)){
                     data[row][j] = word.charAt(index);

                     index++;
                 }

                 else{ i=0; continue;}


             }
         }

         if(choice==1){
             for(int j=start; j<start+word.length(); j++){
                 if(data[j][row]==0 || data[j][row]==word.charAt(index)){
                    data[j][row] = word.charAt(index);

                    index++;
                 }

                 else{ i=0; continue;}
             }
         }

           curWord++;
          }



       for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
         for(int j=0; j<data[i].length; j++){
            if(data[i][j]==0)
             System.out.print("A ");
            else    
             System.out.print(data[i][j]+" ");
         }

         System.out.println();
        }


    }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {



    WordSearch check = new WordSearch();

    check.getMatrix();

 }
}
```

I set up an `if else` statement for if the character of the word were to printed on top of a different character or word then the `for loop` (the one above the `do while`) would be restarted in order to make sure that the word is printed out correctly.

I am having one problem, though. The program seems to work about 50% and prints out something like this:

```
A A h A A A A f A 
A A a A A l A e A 
A A m A A a A n A 
A A b A A d A c A 
A A u A A y A e A 
A A r A A b A A A 
A A g A A u A A A 
A A e A A g A A A 
A A r A A A A A A
```

Occasionally I get this error and this error only (at this specific index):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at WordSearch.getMatrix(WordSearch.java:59)
at WordSearch.main(WordSearch.java:132)
```

What could be the problem?

Edit: Here is what is being read into the program from the file:

```
ladybug
hamburger
fence
```

Comment: Can you show us your input to the program that generates the error?

Comment: What are you trying to do in your if(choice) blocks?

Comment: @pczeus Sorry about that. I put it in the original post at the bottom.

Comment: @pczeus The if(choice) just generates a random number, either 0 or 1, in order to print the word out horizontally or vertically.

Comment: The error tells you, that you try to get a value from an array, but the index provided is outside the array bounds. The line is: String word=words.get(curWord); Your for loop loops with the variable i. Dont you want to use i as the index in this case? The index you want to address is 3. Its 0 based so this would be the fourth element. But you only have three words.

Comment: So, if you run the program with this exact same input every time, occasionally you will get this error?

Comment: @pczeus Yes, exactly. What I'm trying to do with restarting the for loop is restart the for loop but start on the current word but just change where it will be printed. So if ladybug worked fine but hamburger didn't then the for loop would restart and leave ladybug in the spot that it was originally in and then find a new spot for hamburger.

Comment: @pczeus He uses Math.random a lot. It seems these values also control the program flow somehow. So its actually possible for this code to fail occasionally

Comment: Ok looked at you code a little more. I still dont get what are doing at all. But this loop: for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++) is wrong. You only use i to check if its 0 and then continue. And thats it. This loop goes through all words, but you address your words with curWord instead of i. Also while checking if there is space, you actually store the word. If you found out there is no space, you stop storing the word, but the characters till that point remain. I strongly suggest you completly rethink your program flow. There is a reason i, anyone else and yourself dont know whats going on.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I cleaned up your code a little bit by extracting the common logic in your for loops into a method for readability and reuse. Also, the else condition was causing you an issue and was unnecessary by resetting the 'i' back to 0 and causing an occasional error.

Please try this modified code and let me know if you continue to get an error. After running it about 20 times consecutively, I no longer see an issue:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class WordSearch {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

        private void getMatrix(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            String largest = "";
            char[][] data;
            int col = 0;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String first = sc.nextLine();
                words.add(first);

                if(first.length() > largest.length()){
                    largest = first;
                    col = largest.length();
                }
            }

            data = new char[col][col];
            int curWord = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
                String word = words.get(curWord);
                int start = 0;
                int row = 0;
                int choice = 0;

                do{
                    start = (int)(Math.random()*data.length);
                    row =  (int)(Math.random()*data.length);
                    choice = (int)(Math.random()*2);
                }
                while(start + word.length() > data.length);

                updateData(choice, start, row, word, data);
                curWord++;
            }

            for (char[] aData : data) {
                for (char anAData : aData)
                    if (anAData == 0)
                        System.out.print("A ");
                    else
                        System.out.print(anAData + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        private void updateData(int choice, int start, int row, String word, char[][] data){

            for(int index = 0, j = start; j < start + word.length(); j++){
                switch(choice){
                    case 0:
                        if(data[row][j] == 0 || data[row][j] == word.charAt(index)){
                            data[row][j] = word.charAt(index);
                            index++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if(data[j][row] == 0 || data[j][row] == word.charAt(index)){
                            data[j][row] = word.charAt(index);
                            index++;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private String getRandomLetter(){
            Random r = new Random();
            char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
            return ("" + c).toUpperCase();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            WordSearch check = new WordSearch();
            check.getMatrix("/home/cameron/Desktop/words");
        }
    }
```

The program is pretty neat, good job. To make it a little more interesting, I added/changed a couple of things, which you can use or not use to your liking.

Notice I added the `getRandomLetter()` method. That way you can use random letters instead of just 'A' every time to fill in the matrix and looks more like  true word-search. I also upper-cased the original words and each random letter, by changing the line where you add the word from the file to the words list:

```
words.add(first.toUpperCase());
```

Now the output looks like:

```
K M D X H A L B H 
C M L G A W N F F 
M V W Z M D T O T 
L A D Y B U G T Y 
Y J U J U R D V C 
C I C O R P P I L 
B B P R G R Q L X 
D B D V E X R V K 
E I J H R G L D B
```

Comment: But still. If i understood the question right, the point is to find out if the word can be written without crossing another one. But in updateData it allready starts storing the word! Yeah it stops, if there is another word, but the characters till that point remain.

Comment: Thank you for this update. However, @MarioDekena, I don't think the problem with the original code is the fact that it stores the word before it begins. In essence, the program should keep all of the words already printed in the program there if they work. I'm trying to just change the location of where the current word will be printed, not all of them if something with one of the words doesn't work.